# How can I change region for role after initial deployment at Azure?

Tags: azure

How can I change region for role after initial deployment? I can't find any option to do this.
It's only available first time at initial upload.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the service namespace, you associate it with a specific region. The only way to reassociated it currently is to delete and recreate it. Keep in mind it takes a bit for a namespace to be fully purged and subsequently available for reassignment. And anyone can grab that namespace if its available, so there's no guarantee you'll get it again.

In these situations, what I normally direct people to do is first set up a c-name forwarded for the existing service namespace, then change all external endpoints to redirect to this new forwarding address. Next, deploy a new instance of the service to a new namespace and smoke test it to ensure its working properly. Lastly, change the forwarded to point to the new namespace and remove the old one once you're certain its no longer receiving any traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to setup a c-name forward as Brent mentioned, but use the Azure Traffic Manager and then you can host in multiple data centers and have traffic directed to the closest one based on where the client is coming in from.